# Posting HTTP data fails to POST between Android and HTTP Server

Tags: java, android, http, post, http-post

I've built and app which sends data to an HTTP server which I've verified as working using a test.php file then verifying the data succesfully passed between the Android app and the server. Anyways, I modified the source code to send a different string of data:

```
http://gamedemo.hostzi.com/apply.cgi?submit_button=Wireless_MAC&change_action=&action=Apply&wl_macmode=allow&wl_maclist=32&wait_time=3&wl_mac_filter=1&start=&wl_macmode1=allow&m0=00%3A1E%3A33%3AFE%3A0D%3A38&m16=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m1=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m17=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m2=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m18=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m3=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m19=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m4=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m20=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m5=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m21=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m6=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m22=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m7=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m23=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m8=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m24=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m9=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m25=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m10=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m26=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m11=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m27=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m12=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m28=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m13=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m29=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m14=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m30=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m15=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m31=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&end=
```

and it's not passing the data! Any ideas why?

p.s.

I used a tutorial - but when I edited the source to send a specific string of data - instead of the text inputted in a text field (which I no longer need to use) I appear to have butchered the source code.

Tutorial:

http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nfc.linkingmanager.DeviceConfig.MyAsyncTask;


    public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

         private long rowID; 
         private EditText nameEt;
         private EditText capEt;
         private EditText codeEt;
         private TimePicker timeEt;

         public class DeviceConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

                private EditText value;
                private Button btn;
                private ProgressBar pb;
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.deviceconfig);
                    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                            // out of range
                            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
                        }


                } 

                private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

                    @Override
                    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        postData(params[0]);
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
                    }

                    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1/apply.cgi");

                        try {
                            // Add your data
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit_button", "Wireless_MAC");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("change_action", "");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "Apply");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_macmode", "allow");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_maclist", "32");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wait_time", "3");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_mac_filter", "1");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", "allow");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_macmode1", "allow");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m0", "00%3A1E%3A33%3AFE%3A0D%3A38");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m16", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m1", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m17", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m2", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m18", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m3", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m19", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m4", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m20", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m5", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m21", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m6", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m22", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m7", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m23", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m8", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m24", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m9", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m25", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m10", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m26", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m11", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m27", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m12", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m28", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m13", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m29", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m14", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m30", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m15", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m31", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00");
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end", "");

                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                            // Execute HTTP Post Request
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }

           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
           {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
              setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

              nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
              capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
              codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
              timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);




              Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

              if (extras != null)
              {
                 rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
                 nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
                 capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
                 codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
                 String time = extras.getString("time");
                 String[] parts = time.split(":");
                 timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
                 timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
                 timeEt.setIs24HourView(false);
                 DecimalFormat df =   new DecimalFormat  ("00");
                 String minutes = df.format(min);

              }

              Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
              saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v) 
                  {
                     if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                     {
                        AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                           new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                           {
                              @Override
                              protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                              {
                                 saveContact();
                                 return null;
                              }

                              @Override
                              protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                              {
                                 finish();
                              }
                           }; 

                        saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                     }

                     else
                     {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                        alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                        alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                        alert.show();
                     }
                  } 
             });
           }


               private void saveContact() 
               {
                  DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

                  if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
                  {
                      dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                              capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                  + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString());

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                             nameEt.getText().toString(),
                                capEt.getText().toString(),
                                  timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                      + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                                  codeEt.getText().toString());
                  }
               }
    }}}
```

PROBLEMS:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 139    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 138    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 137    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 136    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 143    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 142    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 141    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 140    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 147    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 146    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 145    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 144    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 151    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 150    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 149    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 148    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 154    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 155    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 152    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 153    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 158    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 159    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 156    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 157    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 162    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 163    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 160    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 161    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 166    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 167    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 164    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 165    Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type AsyncTask<String,Integer,Double>  AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 187    Java Problem
The constructor DatabaseConnector(AddEditCountry.DeviceConfig.MyAsyncTask) is undefined AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 258    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 169    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 168    Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type AddEditCountry.DeviceConfig.MyAsyncTask must override or implement a supertype method   AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 185    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 170    Java Problem
The type com.test.app.DeviceConfig.MyAsyncTask is not visible   AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 129    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 130    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 131    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 132    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 133    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 134    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /TEST App/src/com/app/test  line 135    Java Problem
```

PS

- When I attempt to add a ) on the suggested line - it just adds MORE problems to the Problems log. : (
- When I click the submit button it requires the text box to contain data: I'd like to only send my data and remove this requirement if possible

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: The data I'm attempting to send isn't being sent / parsed - I think its still referring to the text box or something

Comment: No exceptions are raised?

Comment: your doinbackground() has the return type of Double but you are returing nothing that may be an issue.

Comment: How can this be resolved?

Comment: I changed it to protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {     is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit_button=Wireless_MAC&change_action=&action=Apply", valueIWantToSend));
```

To:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit_button", "Wireless_MAC");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("change_action", "");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "Apply");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", valueIWantToSend);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I updated my source accordingly using the naming convetion above - anyone see any problems? It's still not passing the data